# Return a response from custom URL scheme

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Trying to figure out if you can send any sort of response back to an application that calls another application through a custom URL scheme.

For example, the 'client' app does the following:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myappscheme://"]];
```

And another app that is registered for **myappscheme://** has the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    // Do something
    return YES;
}
```

The question is can I get information (Even just a char array) back to the application that called **openURL** as a response.  I realize I could just have the 'client' make it's own custom URL scheme, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Unless you make a call back to the client through a URL scheme then no (that would also be horribly messy UX). Apple prohibits apps from communicating with each other unless it's via URL Scheming.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm asking if that is really the only way.  But I guess if it is, then it is essentially the same.  Seems odd that there isn't a standard request->response model though.

Comment: That's it unless both apps are from the same developer. Then you can share data using a private, named pasteboard.

Comment: Yep, had considered that route, but it seemed kludgey and hard to make it event driven.  Might just end up using a combination of the two.  Custom URL that contains a private pasteboard name, the app registered to the custom URL then pastes the response to that pasteboard.  Very ugly, but would work.  Will leave this open a while longer though to see if there is anything cleaner (Although it seems unlikely)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only way to do it has been to use a custom URL scheme, that sends the name of a unique pasteboard, that then acts a temporary communication channel for the two applications.